# How to create a recursive algorithm to create a tree in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have a database table with records that have `StructureGuid` and `ParentGuid`. So most parents have a child.

I want to create a recursive algorithm to build the tree.

The class of the tree is `Header.java`:

```
public class Header implements MultiLevelExpIndListAdapter.ExpIndData {
  private List<Header> mChildren;
  private boolean mIsGroup;
  private int mGroupSize;

  public String header;
  public String structureGuid;

  public Header(String header, String guid){
    this.header = header;
    this.structureGuid = guid;
    mChildren = new ArrayList<Header>();
    setIndentation(0);
  }

  @Override public List<? extends MultiLevelExpIndListAdapter.ExpIndData> getChildren() {
    return mChildren;
  }

  @Override public boolean isGroup() {
    return mIsGroup;
  }

  @Override public void setIsGroup(boolean b) {
    mIsGroup = b;
  }

  @Override public void setGroupSize(int i) {
    mGroupSize = i;
  }

  public int getGroupSize() {
    return mGroupSize;
  }

  public void addChild(Header child){
    mChildren.add(child);
    child.setIndentation(getIndentation() + 1);
  }
}
```

I use an SQL framework to get the root nodes and then I loop through them. The stop case is when a node (`Header`) does not have any children.

The code:

```
//Get the root nodes
public static List<Header> getHeaders(){
    List<Structure> list = new Select().from(Structure.class)
        .where(Condition.column(Structure$Table.PARENTGUID).eq(""))
        .and(Condition.column(Structure$Table.STATUS).eq(true))
        .and(Condition.column(Structure$Table.REQUIRED).eq(true))
        .orderBy("Sequence ASC").queryList();

    ArrayList<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Structure struct: list){
      headers.add(new Header(struct.getDescription(), struct.StructureGUID));
    }

    return addChildren(list, headers);
  }

//recursively return child nodes
  public static List<Header> addChildren(List<Structure> structures, List<Header> headers){
    List<Header> newHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    //recurring algorithm - while there are no kids get headers
    if(headers.size() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        //get children of that header - if none return empty arraylist
        //else loop through and addChildren
        List<Structure> list = new Select().from(Structure.class)
            .where(Condition.column(Structure$Table.PARENTGUID).eq(headers.get(i).structureGuid))
            .and(Condition.column(Structure$Table.STATUS).eq(true))
            .and(Condition.column(Structure$Table.REQUIRED).eq(true))
            .orderBy("Sequence ASC").queryList();

        List <Header> temp = new ArrayList<Header>();

        Log.e("TAG", "size of array: " + list.size());

        if (list.size() != 0) {
          for (Structure struct : list) {
            headers.get(i).addChild(new Header(struct.getDescription(), struct.StructureGUID));
            temp.add(headers.get(i));
          }
        }
        newHeader = addChildren(list, temp);
      }
    }
    return newHeader;
  }
```

Right now it gets stuck in a continuous loop on the first child of the first root node.

Comment: Why recursion? Don't you have a recordset from SQL? Obtain parents and append children if you already know what child belong to a parent.

Comment: @fantaghirocco You see it is like a tree in structure, so children of one element have children of their own. I have to know beforehand the tree length, if I don't want to recur, also it is more unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using Delphi not long ago, without using a recursive approach.

- obtain both parents and children with a single query sorted by the `parent_id`: this allow to have the root nodes first (the elements which have `null` `parent_id`)
- when fetching the recorset:

  - attach the parents (the elements which have children) to the tree and put the attached nodes in a `map` like `<element_id,node>`
  - when fetching children (the elements which have a parent), search for their parent node (the `parent_id`) in the `map` and you'll find the node where the child must be attached to